Gihtub actions build project using boost
I using boost library, but I can't get the CI/CD working for windows-latest as it keeps saying the boost library is not found.
On Linux, this was simple, I only added:
run: |
  sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

to my .yml. On Windows, however, I can't seem to figure out what to do. Does anybody know? I can't find an example.
Thank you.
EDIT:
I tried this
and reduced it to
  - name: Install boost
    uses: MarkusJx/install-boost@v2.4.5
    id: install-boost
    with:
      boost_version: 1.78.0
      toolset: msvc

Which installs boost on windows, but the headers are not found by the compiler.

If there are no dedicated actions for that, choose your package manager (conan, nuget, vcpackage, ...) or build it yourself.

Have you tried this?https://github.com/marketplace/actions/download-and-install-boost

@Arun Yeah I tried that, but boost is not found: error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/math/interpolators/cardinal_cubic_b_spline.hpp': No such file or directory
